# Obtaining user's heading using Accelerometer and Magnetometer

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to obtain a value for the user's heading on an Android phone, using only the Accelerometer and Magnetometer sensors. I have been looking through many other solutions but I am getting a few problems when trying to implement my own code.

Here is the code:

```
if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD){
    Log.d("MAG_FIELD", "ITS A MAG FIELD");

        //aX, aY, aZ are raw accelerometer values 
        float aTheta = (float) Math.atan2(-aX, aZ);
        float aPhi = (float) Math.atan2(-aY, aZ);

        //Obtaining the current magnetometer readings
        float mDegX = event.values[0];
        float mDegY = event.values[1];
        float mDegZ = event.values[2];

        float rotationVectorX = (float) ((mDegX * Math.cos(aPhi)) + (mDegY *Math.sin(aTheta) * Math.sin(aPhi)) - (mDegZ * Math.cos(aTheta) * Math.sin(aPhi)));
        float rotationVectorY = (float) ((mDegY * Math.cos(aTheta)) + (mDegZ * Math.sin(aTheta)));

        //HEADING calculation

        float heading = (float)  Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(rotationVectorY /rotationVectorX)));

        if(rotationVectorX >= 0.0f && rotationVectorY >=0.0f) {}
        else if(rotationVectorX < 0.0f && rotationVectorY >= 0.0f) {heading = 180 - heading ;}
        else if(rotationVectorX < 0.0f && rotationVectorY < 0.0f) {heading = 180 + heading;}
        else if(rotationVectorX >= 0.0f && rotationVectorY < 0.0f){heading = 360 - heading;}
```

My problems are:

1. The heading is constantly off by about 90 degrees when the device
   is flat
2. The heading changes when the screen is changed from being flat on a surface - I am needing it to be the same

Answer (score 1):

Using Magnetometer and accelerometer You can find the device heading in real time.This works even when your device is not on a flat surface.

```
 if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            geomag[0]=event.values[0];
            geomag[1]=event.values[1];
            geomag[2]=event.values[2];
        }

 if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float alpha = 0.8f;

            gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
            gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
            gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];               
        }

            rotationMatrix = new float[16];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, gravity, geomag);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix,vals);

            double Heading=vals[0] * (180/Math.PI);
```